# Working with PhysicalConstants

Tags: syntax, physicalconstants-package

I recently found the `` PhysicalConstants` `` package. First I thought this was nice, since I didn't have to look up some quantities all the time and copy them into the worksheet. But then I noticed the carried units. This is not automatically a bad thing, but it seems to me that they do not go together well, because Wolfram didn't just use base units. Consequently, if I use a quantity in `Newton` and divide it by a quantity in `Meter/Second^2`, the result will be `Newton*Second^2/Meter`, and not `Kilogram`. In my first try this made a huge mess in the result.

Is there a way to work with these in a useful way?

Comment: `Convert[Newton*Second^2/Meter, Kilogram]`.

Comment: What I'd really want to see implemented are functions that might be called `SIBaseUnitsExpand[]`, `MKSBaseUnitsExpand[]`, and `CGSBaseUnitsExpand[]`, that perform the expansion of derived units entirely in terms of base units for the corresponding measurement systems...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As J.M. comments, but opts not to post as an answer, you can use `Convert` in the Units package to convert between types.  Be sure to [read the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Units/guide/UnitsPackage.html) on that package.

```
Needs["Units`"]

Convert[(32.5 Newton)/(7 Meter/Second^2), Kilogram]
```

> 4.64286 Kilogram

**You will also find use in the [Automatic Units package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/) described on [the Wolfram Blog.](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/09/automatic-physical-units-in-mathematica/)**

Comment: One wonders why the functionality of "Automatic Units" has not already been incorporated in the package shipped with *Mathematica*... \*grumbles\*

Comment: @J.M. why did you not post an answer, and then why did you not vote for mine?  I find your actions perplexing.

Comment: I'm out of votes, so I owe you a vote tomorrow. And no, I don't want rep for answering this question...

Comment: The automatic unit package seems fine.

The Convert version ... well, one needs to know what should come out for that. That is not always the case for single factors, for example - at least not without unnecessary thinking.

Comment: @mcandril thanks for the Accept.  Since that is the part of the answer you find most helpful I shall put it in bold.

Answer (score 8):

The units associated with physical constants do not play nicely with expressions that expect a numerical value. If you want only the numerical value of a constant, use `Part`. A motivating example:

```
Needs["PhysicalConstants`"];

Plot[1/Sqrt[1 - v^2/SpeedOfLight^2], {v, 0, 0.9 SpeedOfLight}]

 (* Plot::plln: Limiting value (2.69813*10^8 Meter)/Second in {v,0,0.9 SpeedOfLight} is not a machine-sized real number. >> *)    

c=SpeedOfLight[[1]]
 (* 299792458 *)

Plot[1/Sqrt[1 - v^2/c^2], {v, 0, 0.9 c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see why using `Part` works, turn the constant into a list:

```
List@@SpeedOfLight
 (* {299792458, Meter, 1/Second} *)
```

or look at its `FullForm`:

```
FullForm@SpeedOfLight
 (* Times[299792458, Meter, Power[Second, -1]] *)
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I am unable to see how this is an answer to the question.  Perhaps you could include an explanation of how one would use this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I must disagree that it is not an answer. It provides a simple, if unexplained, way for stripping off the units. I'd say the answer can be improved by discussing why this works. Also, the only caution for this method is that by stripping off the units you're no longer able to check if they're correct.

Comment: @Mr OP indicated interest initially in the numerical quantities,  only to find inconvenient units attached to them. I use the Part@ routinely in problems requiring the values but not the units. I will update with an example later.

Comment: Thank you, I now see that interpretation. +1

Answer (score 3):

With version 9, this is now possible using this method:

```
Plot[1/Sqrt[1 - v^2/QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]]]^2], {v, 0,0.9*QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]]] }]
```